# Encoding Option in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have data file which contains some Chinese data. I am not able to read/write data properly. I have used Encoding/Charset option while reading and writing but no luck. I have to set encoding/charset option while reading and writing csv file.

I have tried the following two options:

```
.option("encoding", "utf-16")

.option("charset","UTF-16")
```

How should the encoding be set?

Comment: What kind error you get. Please update

Comment: No error and I am not getting required output for chinese data.Unable to read/write data properly. we are getting multiple language data Japnese,Chainese etc. Thats why I want set encoding option as "UTF-16"

Comment: Your way of setting the encoding is correct, both ways should work. Does it work for the other languages (other than chinese)? You need to make sure the encoding of the files themselves are `UTF-16`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some trouble reading files with Chinese before with Scala, although not with the Spark platform. Are you sure the encoding used is `UTF-16`? You can open the file with notepad or equivalent to check. In my case, I finally succeeded to read the files with the `GB2312` encoding.

If it doesn't work I would recommend to try using a pure Scala or Java application (without Spark) to see if reading/writing works for the `UTF-16` encoding.